# Making search bar in django

Tags: python, html, django, search, searchbar

Im trying to make a search bar in django and watched several youtube totorials and none of those worked. What im trying to do is either make a search bar that redirects to articles/what_you_searched_for or if not possible show up results that include search. If someone has enough time they can tell me how to do both :).
in views.py:

```
def index(request):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    number_of_records = article.objects.count()
    random_page = random.randint(1,number_of_records)
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "random_page": random_page
    }

#    query = ""
#    if request.GET:
#        query = request.GET['q']
#        context['query'] = str(query)


    entries = util.list_entries()
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", context)
    #{
        #"entries": util.list_entries(),
        #"random_page": random_page,
    #})
def dynamic_articles_view(request, my_id):
    obj = article.objects.get(id= my_id)
    number_of_records = article.objects.count()
    random_page = random.randint(1,number_of_records)
    context = {
        "object": obj,
        "random_page": random_page
    }
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/article_detail.html", context)
```

in index.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1 id="demo" onclick="add_article()">Article</h1>


    <ul>

        {% for instance in object_list %}
            <li><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/{{instance.id}}/">{{instance.title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

layout.html:                 ------------  SEARCH BAR HERE ---------

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action = "/articles/{{q}}">                         __________EXACTLY HERE ________
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href = "/new_article" >Create New Article</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/{{random_page}}">Random Page</a>
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from encyclopedia import views
from encyclopedia.views import index, new_article, dynamic_articles_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls")),
    path('new_article/', new_article),
    path('home/', index, name = 'home'),
    path('articles/<int:my_id>/', dynamic_articles_view, name = 'articless')
]
```

encyclopedia urls (other folder):

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("", views.new_article, name="new_article")
]
```

if needed i will comment models and forms but i dont want to make my question to long.

Comment: Firstly, you should use `{% url 'URL_NAME' %}` in all your hrefs. Don't write custom url including the localhost IP. It will be a pain to change it all later

Comment: And what are you trying to search by? Article title? Text included in the article content?

Comment: And what does your urls.py look like?

Comment: yes im trying to serach by article title. i added urls in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to add a GET `form` in your template with a `search` input without setting the action of the form:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search by title" value="{{request.GET.title}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Then in the `views.py` in the  you get the value. If it's given, you filter by it:

```
def dynamic_articles_view(request):
    context['object_list'] = article.objects.filter(title__icontains=request.GET.get('search'))
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/article_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: Add print outs to check which part doesnt work - form, param, filter?

Comment: i already fixed it with (kinda) with:     if request.GET:
        queryset = article.objects.filter(title__icontains='zdf') but i dont know how to change the 'zdf' to query cuz it gives me error that its not defined

Comment: Have you tried `request.GET.get('title')` in place of `'zdf'`?

Comment: then it probably doesn't find the records. You should debug the GET request params and check if the values are correct. Cause that should work or the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: I fixed it by :query = request.GET.get('search') in index view also i renamed name of form to search. thanks for help

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. can u accept it so it gets closed?